# Selection of booster for Mercury capsule

Tags: launch-vehicle, project-mercury

How did NASA verify that "Redstone (PGM 11?) was the most suitable rocket to launch Mercury capsule (1st launch)? From books like "Project Mercury - a chronology", and "This new Ocean - a history of project Mercury", I understand Redstone was selected just because it was the most powerful and dependable rocket in those times (later it was replaced by Atlas - when it became available). It is unlikely that NASA would not have checked Redstone's suitability for the mission. Is there any record about NASA cross checking the capacity of Redstone, w.r.t. payload (the capsule weight with astronaut), and the maximum altitude and orbital velocity achievable with that payload ?

Comment: Isn't "it was the most powerful and dependable rocket in those times" exactly the point in "NASA would [...] have checked Redstone's suitability for the mission"?

Comment: @CallMeTom: You may be right, but simply being "most powerful rocket" within those available in those days, may not have been sufficient. What if the Payload would have been more than Redstone's capacity? What if Redstone was unable to reach the required altitude &/or What if it would not have been able to impart the "horizontal" velocity, required to orbit in that altitude? I believe NASA would have cross checked all that and then only decided on Redstone. It would have been a matter of "surety" and "Cost". Any way lets see if anyone else has any document to this effect.

Comment: @Niranjan - it isn't like they designed and built the capsule and then looked around to see if anything could launch it.

Comment: In fact, Redstone wasn’t nearly powerful enough to put the Mercury capsule into orbit; it was only used for a few suborbital flights.

Comment: @Russel Borogove: You seem quite convincing on that. Perhaps that's the reason the first two flights could not complete even one full orbit. I am not sure if NASA intended them to be so, but if so, it looks like NASA was aware about Redstone not being suitable for even one full orbit flight. In such a case, Redstone might have been selected  just because it was the best option NASA had then. But then the question then gets transferred to selection of "ATLAS". Did NASA confirm ATLAS capabilities prior to its selection? Any record of that?

Comment: @Jon Custer: May be so, but then how did they select the launch vehicle - both Redstone for the first two flights, and then Atlas for the subsequent ones? Can you throw some light on that?

Comment: Yes, both the Redstone and Atlas capabilities were well understood before any flights; it was nothing like slapping the Mercury on top of a rocket and seeing how far it got.  The Redstone flights were never intended to be orbital.

Comment: @Russel Borogove: Refer book "History of the Redstone missile systems" by John Bullard, (1965). While ABMA tried to market use of their missile to Mercury program managers, NASA did not pay any attention. Suddenly the Russians orbited Yuri Gagarin, and the US had a huge loss of face. US could not afford any time to analyze, & as a "knee jerk response", selected what ever was available, to at least "touch the space", ASAP.  That's the basic reason that details about verification of suitability of Redstone vis-à-vis Mercury are not readily available - (NASA simply trusted ABMA proposal).

Answer (score 8):

> I understand Redstone was selected just because it was the most powerful and dependable rocket in those times

The primary driver for the selection of both the Atlas and the Redstone for Mercury was cost and time, rather than capability. Those rockets were already in production, meaning that only relatively inexpensive changes were needed to adapt them to the Mercury program.

Atlas was actually [less powerful than the Mercury program would have liked](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4201/ch4-4.htm):

> using the Atlas [instead of a newly designed booster] would mean reducing the orbital altitude of the 2,000-3,000-pound capsule from about 170 miles to about 115 miles. This in turn would mean that voice contact would be lost for long periods unless more orbital tracking stations were built around the globe.

Redstone, in turn, was a relatively short-range missile, and had nowhere near the payload capability of the Atlas. The basic military version of the Redstone wasn't powerful enough to put the Mercury capsule on the desired suborbital trajectory of the first few flights, let alone to orbit. The [Mercury Redstone was adapted from the Jupiter-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Redstone_Launch_Vehicle#Modifications_from_the_Redstone_missile) version of the missile.

In any case, to address your actual question, I am unable to find any description of the evaluation process. I assume NASA and USAF had the capability of doing computer simulation of ballistic trajectories in the late 1950s; the algorithms for doing so are straightforward. The simulation programs would have been validated against actual flight tests to confirm their correctness.

The real-life performance of the rockets was somewhat variable due to inconsistencies in manufacture and guidance problems. For instance, [MR-2, the second Mercury-Redstone flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Redstone_2) (with Ham the chimpanzee aboard), overshot the planned landing area by over 200 km. The problems with MR-2 were solved, and the subsequent uncrewed test flight, MR-BD, went according to plan and hit just 8 km from its target point.

Comment: "was cost and time, " Emphasis on time - the whole Space Race thing. +1

Comment: @Russel borogove: I have read about both the points you have mentioned. I am very sure that NASA would have done the validation process, if not directly, then indirectly. NASA might have given the payload, altitude and velocity data to AF/ABMA etc, who would have recommended them the launcher from their stables. It would have been very stupid of NASA not to have any level of surety about the fulfillment of their objective, prior to launch. The administration would have seriously questioned them on this, if it would have failed. May be such things are intentionally hidden. Hope to know...

Comment: @Organic Marble: While I agree that Cost and Time frame (beating the Russians) would have been very critical, was there no need to be successful? Or simply "a good attempt" - regardless of possible failure, was sufficient enough for NASA / US administration in those days? After all it was also about US prestige.. wasn't it?

Comment: @Russel Borogove: Also I am skeptical about computer simulation. Even Apollo 11 computers were very basic in nature, that of "AND/NAND/NOR/OR" gates. (Although I assume any kind/amount of analysis and inference has to happen through these gates only - but I am not literate enough in this field). If they would have had "computer simulation" techniques then, Apollo computers might have been different.

Comment: @Niranjan the national objective was to do a crewed spaceflight ASAP. There was no rational choice other than to use boosters that had already been developed for the military.

Comment: @Organic Marble: It seems you are saying "making an attempt with available resources was more important than being sure about success" - correct? If so, certainly NASA did their best. Agreed.

Comment: All computers are at their root made of logic gates; that doesn't signify. The computers available in the late 1950s were large, slow, and unreliable, but more than adequate to do this kind of work. A moderately detailed ballistic simulation run might take a day to run instead of the fraction of a second it would take today, but it could be done. The guidance calculations done by the Apollo LM during landing were only a little simpler than those of a launch simulation, and they could be done in real-time on a computer small enough to fit in the LM!

Comment: @Organic Marble: Refer book "History of the Redstone missile systems" by John Bullard, (1965). While ABMA tried to market use of their missile to Mercury program managers, NASA did not pay any attention. Suddenly the Russians orbited Yuri Gagarin, and the US had a huge loss of face. US could not afford any time to analyze, & as a "knee jerk response", selected what ever was available, to at least "touch the space", ASAP. That's the basic reason that details about verification of suitability of Redstone vis-à-vis Mercury are not readily available - (NASA simply trusted ABMA proposal).

Comment: Yes, there was no rational choice other than to use boosters that had already been developed for the military.

Comment: Computer simulations were done for a suitable definition of "computer" -- i.e., "computer" was a job title, usually held by women (many of them black). See "Hidden Figures". (And yes, the movie at least suggests that by the time of the first Atlas launches, they also were using electronic computers.)

Answer (score 0):

Refer book "History of the Redstone missile systems" by John Bullard, (1965). While ABMA tried to market use of their missile to Mercury program managers, NASA did not pay any attention. Suddenly the Russians orbited Yuri Gagarin, and the US had a huge loss of face. US could not afford any time to analyze, & as a "knee jerk response", selected what ever was available, to at least "touch the space", ASAP. That's the basic reason that details about verification of suitability of Redstone vis-à-vis Mercury are not readily available - (NASA simply trusted ABMA proposal).